# What does this jquery code do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('[role="button"]').click(function () {
            myMethod();
        });
```

I know that on click on something it calls `myMethod()`, but on click on what?

What does `role` mean?

Is this button?

```
<input type="button" ... />
```

What is: `[role="button"]` ?

Comment: If you want to work with jQuery, I recommend that you get used to the docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector. `$('[role="button"]')` would select all elements that has attribute `role` set to `button`.

**For ex:**
All below three will be selected when you do `$('[role="button"]')`

```
<div role="button" ></div>
<p role="button" ></p>
<button role="button"></button>
```

But this will not

```
<input type="button">
```

Answer (score 3):

Selector with attribute role whose value is button

```
$('[role="button"]')  ; // It is not the button in context
```

//

```
<input role="button" ... />  // this is selected
    <input type="button" ... />  // Not this
    <input role="button" ... />  // this is selected
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector is selecting on the `role` attribute that is equal to `button`.

Answer (score 1):

It's the attribute equals selector

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/